# I want to load an image without the extra white pixels. How do I do this?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, transparency

When i draw in image on a canvas, the white pixels surrounding the image are there too to the image boundries. Any tips on how to prevent this?

Comment: You need to draw a transparent image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272583/drawing-transparent-images-in-java-graphics2d

Comment: I read that and I'm still confused x.x

Comment: If the image isn't transparent to begin with, you can filter it so that the white pixels become transparent, but this will also occur with internal white pixels and so must be done with care.

Comment: I don't have any internal white pixels, so how do I filter it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

class ImageTransparencyByColor {

    public static BufferedImage getTransparentImage(
        BufferedImage image, Color transparent) {
        // must have a transparent image
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g= img.createGraphics();
        for (int x=0; x<img.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<img.getHeight(); y++) {
                if (image.getRGB(x,y)!=transparent.getRGB()) {
                    img.setRGB( x,y, image.getRGB(x,y) );
                }
            }
        }
        g.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL ("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar" +
            "/ab5193916ccf152f96b0a69323e934a1?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG");
        final BufferedImage trans = getTransparentImage(
            ImageIO.read(url), Color.WHITE);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JLabel gui = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(trans));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a .png image. A .gif image has only total/no transpancy.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your image on a JPanel instead. Canvas is a heavyweight component. Alternatively, try to change alpha of your Canvas. `this.setBackground(new Color( 0,0,0,0 );`

EDIT: Try this. Create a class for your image. The way you initialize your Image doesn't matter.

```
public class MyImage extends JPanel {

    private final URL IMG_DIRECTORY = Main.class.getResource("/res/yourImage.png"); // Image directory

    public MyImage() {

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(IMG_DIRECTORY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.setSize(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    }
```

On your Frame class, declare your image class `MyImage yourImage = new MyImage();`, then add it to whatever your ContentPane was.

Comment: If any of my 2 answer didn't help you, please post your SSCCE

Comment: The picture im loading is being overlayed over a series of different colored backgrounds, so i would need to the white pixels to be transparent somehow...